# Tensorflow - classification of videos

Tags: video, tensorflow

Is the open-source version of TensorFlow suitable for classification of videos - akin the examples stated in http://vision.stanford.edu/pdf/karpathy14.pdf ? If not - are there any other packages in the public domain that could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 9):

It would be possible to modify the [image models](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image) shipped with TensorFlow to train a neural network on such video data.

The main challenges would be:

1. Creating a [custom reader](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/new_data_formats/index.html#custom-data-readers) that handled the appropriate video file format (or converting your video data to one of the supported format).
2. Using the [image ops](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image.html#images) to generate the multi-resolution images required in the Karpathy et al. model.
3. (Possibly) [using queues](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html) to perform pipelined video processing and ensure that I/O doesn't become a bottleneck.

Comment: Are there examples of this method being used successfully to classify videos?